# Why doesn't TypeApplications allow partially applied type synonyms to be used

Tags: haskell, type-synonyms

I did some search and thought that `LiberalTypeSynonyms` would allow it. It would allow to use `partially applied type synonyms` as argument to Type in some cases.

```
{-# LANGUAGE LiberalTypeSynonyms #-}

type Value a = ExceptT [a] Identity a
type Apply m a = m a
run1 :: Apply Value a -> IO ()
run1 e = undefined
```

But the following does not work in TypeApplications, why and is it possible to make it compiled?

```
{-# LANGUAGE LiberalTypeSynonyms #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}

type Value a = ExceptT [a] Identity a

run :: m Int -> IO ()
run e = undefined 

main :: IO ()
main = do
    print "begin"
    let a = run @Value 
    print "end"
```

The above code does not compile due to the error

```
    • The type synonym ‘Value’ should have 1 argument, but has been given none
    • In the expression: run @Value
      In an equation for ‘a’: a = run @Value
      In the expression:
        do print "begin"
           let a = run @Value
           print "end"
   |
30 |     let a = run @Value
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This doesn't have much to do with `-XTypeApplications`. Haskell *generally* doesn't allow type synonyms to be used without completely applied arguments. All that `-XLiberalTypeSynonyms` does is circumventing this in case it's possible to inline an entire expression – e.g. if you have

```
{-# LANGUAGE LiberalTypeSynonyms #-}

type IntApplied f = f Int
type List a = [a]

foo :: IntApplied List
foo = [1,2,3]
```

In this case, the type synonyms can just be substituted right there and then to `foo :: [Int]`, before any type checking or instance resolution happens. It's like something a simple macro processor could do.

But in your case you're trying to pass an incomplete type synonym to something else as-is. `run` can't know whether or not the type variable it receives can be “inlined” this way, but it would in general need to be able to *match* on this variable, and that's just not possible on general type-level functions (as you can define with type synonyms/families), it's only possible on *type constructors*.

See https://github.com/ghc-proposals/ghc-proposals/blob/master/proposals/0242-unsaturated-type-families.rst for how Haskell is moving forwards in this subject.

Comment: The kind of `Value` is indeed `Type -> @U Type` under mentioned proposal. **U**nmatchable type functions must appear fully saturated.